# Getting content from Unattached Content Database Data Recovery

Tags: content-database, restore

I'm trying to get some content from restored sql server SharePoint db

So in Central Admin I choose;

**Unattached Content Database Data Recovery**

I feel in my database name and sql server instance and click 
Browse Content and next.

Then I should choose the Site collection from my database content
but the only site collection I see is the one of the Central Admin.

How can I choose the Site Collection included in my unattached content database?

**EDIT:**
I've tried backing up a library with **Unattached Content Database Data Recovery** but I get the following error:

```
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Start Time: 2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM.
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Progress: Initializing Export.
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Progress: Starting Export.
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Progress: Calculating Objects to Export.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:14 PM] Progress: Serializing Objects to Disk.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:14 PM] Progress: Starting to process objects of type Min.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Progress: Finished processing objects of type Min.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Progress: Starting to process objects of type Folder.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi] Progress: Exporting /MySite/Document Condivisi
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi]   Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi]   Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin(String loginName)

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetUserFromMetaInfo(MetaInfoProperty mip, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetMetaInfo(Object metaInfoObject, SPWeb parentWeb, SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] FatalError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetUserFromMetaInfo(MetaInfoProperty mip, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetMetaInfo(Object metaInfoObject, SPWeb parentWeb, SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object topLevelObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.SerializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Progress: Export did not complete.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Finish Time: 2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Duration: 00:09:43
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Total Objects: 2175819
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Finished with 0 warnings.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Finished with 2 errors.
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you are restoring the right content DB.

after that here are the steps(u already did but making sure)

- Enter the DB server name and DB name, Select the Browse Content
- Click Next
- On this page, click on site collection drop and click on change the site collection.
- on this new popup, you will all the site collection, slect the correct one.
- check the backup site collection
- click Next

Comment: I've tried to exporting only a library but I the export doesn't succed with the error above

Comment: finally you get the site collection? if yes, then please start new question as per stackexchange